# Three.js : keep my objects the same time, regardless the height of my window

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to add a THREE.JS scene on my website but I find some issues for its responsive :

If I resize my window on the **x axis** the size of my object is the same :

[image: bottles have the same dimension with different windows width]

But now if I resize my window on the **y axis**, the size of my object change :

[image: bottles doesn't have the same dimension with different windows height]

I want to prevent this behaviour. I would like that the size of my object depends on the width of my window and not on the height of my window.

Does anyone know how to do that ? Thank you very much !

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 4000 );
camera.position.set(-200,-50,0);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x0c0c0d );
scene.add(camera);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

UPDATE :
Regarding TheJim01's answer, I should do some calculations. I simplified my camera position to camera.position.z = 750. Here's a picture I found that illustrates my problem :

[image]

So I think I should do :

```
Math.tan(50/2) = window.innerHeight/2 / camera.position.z
```

so finally :

```
camera.position.z = window.innerHeight/2 / Math.tan(50/2)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: You FOV is 50°, and is height-based. Given that and the viewport height, you must calculate the appropriate camera distance to maintain object size. There's some trigonometry involved, but it's not too bad. Give it a try, and update your question if you have any errors/questions.

Comment: Hi again @TheJim01 and thanks, I just did ! I think I don' have the good value for the opposite side of my rectangle triangle...